# facebook Insights api - Need code/step to authenticate with out user intervention

Tags: c#, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk, console-application

Need Facebook Insights API - Sample code / steps to retrieve the authentication token for an automated windows console application in C#.

We have an automated windows console application in-development in C# to connect to Facebook Insights api to retrieve the data. During the step of authentication, the source code step for authentication, whatever I was able to find through google search, opens up the browser for facebook login. But ours is an automated system, once deployed to the production server, there is no way for the user intervention to hit the login button, etc for the facebook to authenticate. The system should be setup to run automatically without the user intervention. Let me know the steps / documentation / sample code for me to achieve the facebook insights authentication in the console application without the user intervention of hitting the buttons in the browser popup, etc.

Answer (score 1):

first you download this package

http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook.CSharp.SDK/

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object>();
//your application id and secret from https://developers.facebook.com/apps
config.Add("appId", "3955.......");
config.Add("secret", "4c1d...............");
config.Add("fileUpload", true); //optional

FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(config);

var appToken = client.getAccessToken();
client.setAccessToken(appToken);
Console.Writeline(client.fql("SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE      object_id=your_application_id AND metric='application_active_users' AND end_time=end_time_date('your_date') AND period=period('day')"));
```

this should work